# Why can not run multiple SparkContexts at once

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, jupyter-notebook

I use python 2 and spark. I follow an instruction how to count words on twitter on this link https://github.com/Ruthvicp/CS5590_BigDataProgramming/wiki/Lab-Assignment-4----Spark-MLlib-classification-algorithms,-word-count-on-twitter-streaming
I have 2 file
TSWordCount

```
import findspark
findspark.init()
import pyspark
from pyspark import SparkContext
from pyspark.streaming import StreamingContext
from pyspark.sql.functions import desc
from collections import namedtuple
import os
os.environ["SPARK_HOME"] = "C:\\spark-2.3.1-bin-hadoop2.7\\spark-2.3.1-bin-hadoop2.7"
os.environ["HADOOP_HOME"] = "C:\\winutils\\"

def main():
    sc =SparkContext(appName="Countwords1234")
    wordcount = {}
    ssc = StreamingContext(sc, 5)
    lines = ssc.socketTextStream("localhost", 5678)
    fields = ("word", "count")
    Tweet = namedtuple('Text', fields)
    # lines = socket_stream.window(20)
    counts = lines.flatMap(lambda text: text.split(" "))\
        .map(lambda x: (x, 1))\
        .reduceByKey(lambda a, b: a + b).map(lambda rec: Tweet(rec[0], rec[1]))
    counts.pprint()
    ssc.start()
    ssc.awaitTermination()
if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

When i run this file, it is succeed and output is "Listening to port 5678" and my second file is TwitterListener

```
import findspark
findspark.init()
import pyspark
import tweepy
from tweepy import OAuthHandler
from tweepy import Stream
from tweepy.streaming import StreamListener
import socket
import json
import time

consumer_key = '30f****'
consumer_secret = 'smu7B******
access_token = '153*******'
access_secret = 'QIizsB***'


auth = OAuthHandler(consumer_key, consumer_secret)
auth.set_access_token(access_token, access_secret)

class TweetsListener(StreamListener):

    def __init__(self, csocket):
        self.client_socket = csocket

    def on_data(self, data):
        try:
            msg = json.loads(data)
            print(msg['text'].encode('utf-8'))
            self.client_socket.send(msg['text'].encode('utf-8'))
            return True
        except BaseException as e:
            print("Error on_data: %s" % str(e))
        return True

    def on_error(self, status):
        print(status)
        return True


def sendData(c_socket):
    auth = OAuthHandler(consumer_key, consumer_secret)
    auth.set_access_token(access_token, access_secret)

    twitter_stream = Stream(auth, TweetsListener(c_socket))
    twitter_stream.filter(track=['fifa'])


if __name__ == "__main__":
    s = socket.socket()  # Create a socket object
    host = "localhost"  # Get local machine name
    port = 5678 # Reserve a port for your service.
    s.bind((host, port))  # Bind to the port
    print("Listening on port: %s" % str(port))
    s.listen(5)  # Now wait for client connection.
    c, addr = s.accept()  # Establish connection with client.
    print("Received request from: " + str(addr))
    time.sleep(5)
    sendData(c)
```

Like you see file twitter listener listening to port localhost:5678 . Then in file TSWordCount,I use SparkContext(appname="") , i think i should put my app 's name on twitter here so i put Countwors124 there. Then I call to  port by ssc.socketTextStream("localhost",5678).  But i have error at TSWordCount when i run it  appear the error say that
Cannot run multiple SparkContexts at once; existing SparkContext(app=PySparkShell, master=local[*]) created by 
I search the error and i found a solution like use sc.stop() so that i put it  after ssc.awaitTermination(). But it didn't work. What should i do now ?

Answer (score 3):

I found an answer . i replaced `sc =SparkContext(appName="Countwords1234")` with  `sc = SparkContext.getOrCreate()` and everything worked . although i still not understand , at the end of the day result matters LOL